# Unexpected LEFT JOIN behavior with condition in ON clause

Tags: mysql, left-join, filtering, where-clause

I have the following three tables:

- `fees` - has information about a fee on a bill
- `payments` - has information about payments on a bill (including payments to fees)
- `details` - has detailed information about the payment

I'm struggling to understand why my query isn't returning the result I expect.

SQL Fiddle: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/942636/3

```
CREATE TABLE fees (
  receipt_number int(11) NOT NULL,
  bill_number    int(11) NOT NULL,
  version        int(11) NOT NULL,
  fee_id         int(11) NOT NULL,
  fee_type       varchar(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE payments (
  receipt_number int(11) NOT NULL,
  bill_number    int(11) NOT NULL,
  version        int(11) NOT NULL,
  payment_id     int(11) NOT NULL,
  amount         decimal(13,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00'
);

CREATE TABLE details (
  receipt_number int(11) NOT NULL,
  payment_id     int(11) NOT NULL,
  fee_type       varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
  amount         decimal(13,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00'
);

INSERT INTO fees (receipt_number, bill_number, version, fee_id, fee_type)
VALUES (111, 100, 1, 1, 'a'),
       (111, 100, 1, 1, 'b'),
       (111, 100, 1, 2, 'c'),
       (111, 100, 1, 2, 'd');

INSERT INTO payments (receipt_number, bill_number, version, payment_id, amount)
VALUES (111, 100, 1, 98, 30.00),
       (111, 100, 1, 99, 60.00);

INSERT INTO details (receipt_number, payment_id, fee_type, amount)
VALUES (111, 98, 'a', 10.00),
       (111, 98, 'b', 10.00),
       (111, 98, 'd', 10.00),
       (111, 99, 'a', 20.00),
       (111, 99, 'b', 20.00),
       (111, 99, 'c', 20.00);
```

I'm attempting to find out if:

- A bill has a fee with type 'c'
- There is a payment made towards that fee (determined by the fee_type)

My query:

```
SELECT    fees.bill_number, details.receipt_number AS has_payment_type_c
FROM      fees
LEFT JOIN payments
          USING (bill_number, version)
LEFT JOIN details
          ON  details.receipt_number = payments.receipt_number
          AND details.payment_id     = payments.payment_id
          AND details.fee_type = 'c'
WHERE     fees.fee_type = 'c'
AND       details.receipt_number IS NULL;
```

I get the result:

```
bill_number  has_payment_type_c
100          (null)
```

I should **not** see the bill_number in this list, as the bill has a fee and a payment towards that fee.

I am filtering the `details.fee_type` in the ON clause to both reduce the number of records looked up in that table and to only join to that table for that specific fee_type. The query seems to "work" (0 results) by moving the fee_type join condition to the WHERE clause, but I don't think that is correct.

My questions:

1. What am I doing wrong in my query? How can I fix it to produce the result I'm looking for, and how does that fix work?
2. Assuming I get a working query, can I just simply reverse the table order and the SELECT to find the opposite information - payments of a certain fee_type without an associated fee record of that same type?

Comment: Please ask 1 question. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect justified by reference to authoritative documentation or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do.

Comment: It's good you have somewhat of a [mre]. But it should be the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) (Otherwise you are expecting us to walk through the code when you didn't, and you are expecting us to write yet another presentation of the language with no details about what you already misunderstand or do or don't understand.)

Comment: 1. What are the constraints? [mre] 2. NULLs can be from either left join. fees with no payment will have null payments after the 1st join & null details after the 2nd. 3. It is a red flag to have details.fee_type = 'c' in both AND & ON. LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Change the select to select * so you can see everything returned and go from there.

Comment: This is a rather unobvious design. Bills went out in various versions, each for some fees or one fee? Payments were made, each for the one fee, or some of it's bill's version's fees? It is not clear what the state of the system is. You don't give a clear row membership condition (meaning) for each base table & your query or business rules or constraints. Your descriptions of how the query is a function of the base tables or business situation are unclear & fragmented. So we don't know what a correct query would be or what constraints would allow futher query expressions to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use a derived table that inner joins `payments` and `details`, and then left join the derived table to fees:

```
SELECT    DISTINCT fees.bill_number, fees.version, x.bill_number AS has_payment_type_c
FROM      fees
LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT payments.bill_number, payments.version, details.fee_type
             FROM   payments
             JOIN   details
                    USING(receipt_number, payment_id)
             WHERE  details.fee_type = 'c'
) x
           ON  fees.bill_number = x.bill_number
           AND fees.version     = x.version
WHERE    fees.fee_type = 'c'
AND      x.bill_number IS NULL;
```

This will return the expected 0 results, and can be validated by removing the where condition that checks for a null `x.bill_number`:

```
bill_number  version  has_payment_type_c
100          1        100
```

The same approach works for finding payments without a fee. Use a derived table that inner joins payments and details, then left join to fees. SELECT the `fee.bill_number AS has_payment_type_c` and add `WHERE fee.bill_number IS NULL` to the WHERE clause.